# Filling and ScalingFunctions Reverse

Tags: plotting, bugs, filling

Filling and ScalingFunctions->{"Reverse", Automatic} works with Plot but not with ListPlot. Am I missing something?

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Yellow}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic}]
```

[image: Filling works with Plot and ScalingFunction Reverse]

```
d1 = Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
d2 = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
ListPlot[{d1, d2}, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Yellow}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic}]
```

[image: Filling does not work with ListPlot and ScalingFunction Reverse]

Of course the one below works

```
ListPlot[{d1, d2}, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Yellow}}]
```

Comment: It seems to be a bug. For example, using `ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Reverse"}` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems be a bug. Right now we manual add `Reverse` at the data.

```
d1 = Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
d2 = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
ListPlot[Reverse /@ {d1, d2}, Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Yellow}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic}]
```

[image]